# Kafka broker not coming up

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using kafka version 0.11.0.2 on 3 broker cluster and was attaching a new disk to all brokers. Somehow on broker 2, I started getting the following(replaced the actual path with XXXXX) error after restart

```
Found a corrupted index file due to requirement failed: Corrupt index found, index file (/XXXXX/XXXXX/00000000000000000000.index) has non-zero size but the last offset is 0 which is no larger than the base offset 0.}. deleting /XXXXX/XXXXX/00000000000000000000.timeindex, /XXXXX/XXXXX/00000000000000000000.index, and /XXXXX/XXXXX/00000000000000000000.txnindex and rebuilding index... (kafka.log.Log)
```

I've searched and found that it happened due to unclean shutdown and workaround is to delete index file of 10MB
and I cleaned using the following command

```
find /XXXXX -size 10485760c -name *.index -delete
```

Since after this run, I started getting following error and the broker is still getting killed abruptly.

```
ERROR Could not find offset index file corresponding to log file /XXXXX/XXXXX/00000000000000000000.log, rebuilding index... (kafka.log.Log)
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: I don't think this is the error that kills your broker. Kafka will reproduce index files as far as I know. Do you have any additional error logs?